Question about phase estimation and bit string probability
Q) Let $x,N>0$ integers such that $x<N$. Consider the order finding
algorithm that finds the order $r$ of $x$ mod $N$. If $r = 2^{k}$ for some positive integer $k$ then find the probability $p(m_1,...,m_t)$ of obtaining the bit string $m_1...m_t$ as the outcome of the phase estimation (PE) step.
Any and all help with this would be appreciated, the question is related to quantum algorithms and I am struggling to understand what specifically I need to do here.
